# CakePHP Collection Filters Return Different Object Type?

Tags: collections, cakephp-3.x

I'm running into unexpected behavior in CakePHP 3.x when using collection filters. When I provide a collection of type `Cake\Collection\Collection`, the filter returns a new collection with type `Cake\Collection\Iterator\FilterIterator`.

Here is some sample code that demonstrates the behavior:

```
    $people = [
        ['name' => 'Alice', 'age' => 17],
        ['name' => 'Bob', 'age' => 51]
    ];
    $collection = new Collection($people);
    $adults = $collection->filter(function ($person, $key) {
        return $person['age'] > 17;
    });
```

The output of debuging `$collection` and `$adults` shows the type change:

```
object(Cake\Collection\Collection) {
    'count' => (int) 2
}
object(Cake\Collection\Iterator\FilterIterator) {
    'count' => (int) 1
}
```

This object type change is causing unexpected problems in my code. I've resolved the issue by rebuilding the collection after each filter. For example:

```
$adults = new Collection($adults->toArray());
```

This seems a little ugly. Is there a better method for retaining the `Cake\Collection\Collection` type? Any advice appreciated!

Comment: I see where the change to a FilterIterator type is occurring in the [CollectionTrait](https://api.cakephp.org/3.6/source-class-Cake.Collection.CollectionTrait.html#57-71).

Comment: All iterators are collections.

Comment: @ndm Thanks for the swift reply! I'm running into a problem where vanilla Collections and FilterIterators have different `__construct` requirements. If I save a Collection to the session, I can retrieve it without a problem, but the FilterIterator throws an error on retrieval: `Too few arguments to function Cake\Collection\Iterator\FilterIterator::__construct(), 1 passed in /vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Collection/Collection.php on line 70 and exactly 2 expected`. Is this a known issue and is there a workaround that you could recommend that's better than the one I outlined above?

Comment: It is known as in that PHP cannot serialize functions, hence only the data can be stored and restored. If you want to serialize iterators that accept callbacks, you can for example use `Collection::compile()`, which will give you a new collection with all changes applied (it's basically doing what you're doing manually in your example).